# rewrite google sheet reset-filter script to make it shorter

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have these codes that perfectly work fine as I need to be, but if possible, I need to rewrite it to become shorter, using a loop perhaps. This works only up to 5th column, what if I have more than 10, 20 or more filtered columns and I don't want to do again the "filter.removeColumnFilterCriteria(11)...(n);" Thank you for all your help! I'm just new to GAS.

```
  function resetFilter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var filter = ss.getActiveSheet().getFilter();
  
  if (filter !== null) {
    filter.removeColumnFilterCriteria(1);
    filter.removeColumnFilterCriteria(2);
    filter.removeColumnFilterCriteria(3);
    filter.removeColumnFilterCriteria(4);
    filter.removeColumnFilterCriteria(5);
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using for loop and a parameter for the function to make it dynamic

```
function resetFilter(n) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
    filter = ss.getActiveSheet().getFilter();
  
  if(filter !== null) {
    for(var i = 0;i < n; i++) {
      filter.removeColumnFilterCriteria(i);
    }
  }
}

// for example 5
resetFilter(5);
// for example 20
resetFilter(20);
```

Comment: Better to declare `n`  inside the function or give a default value as functions are run directly in apps script( and not from the outside)

Comment: i got this error msg: " Exception: Those columns are out of bounds"

Comment: maybe you are trying to remove columns those never exist!